# GORM: nullable constraint for domain map value

Tags: grails, dictionary, grails-orm, nullable

I have a GORM domain class with a map object.

```
class MyClass {
    Map<String, String> myMap

    static constraints = { ... }
}
```

By default, the values in myMap are non-nullable. Is there a way to configure the constraints such that the values in myMap are nullable?

Answer (score 0):

```
static constraints = {
    myMap nullable: true
}
```

see [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/nullable.html)

Comment: That is not working for me. I am using grails 2.1.0 with oracle. myMap.key is nullable, but myMap.value is not.